# Chevrolet Cruze 2011 oil Type Change

Tags: chevrolet, oil, oil-change, cruze

I've made changed my car oil and they put in synthetic before it was non-synthetic, It's there any problem with this, or its safe?
Do I need next time I change the oil to continue with synthetic or can I return to non-synthetic?
Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No problem as long as it is the correct grade - make sure you top up with the same though.

Comment: In addition make sure the oil is Dexos approved.